# Reverse a percentage

Tags: javascript, math

I have a percentage, it ranges from 50% to 0%.

I need the values to be mirrored, so:

```
0% now equals 50%
1% = 49%
25% = 25%
48% = 2%
50% = 0%
```

etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show your existing code.

Comment: How is it 'stepping down'? You probably want to change your loop. Otherwise you can use (50 - <your number>)

Comment: I've appeared to have misphrased the question, there is not a loop whose indexes I can manipulate, the value that steps down represents a % of how far through the first half of the animation is complete.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain a loop. Where do the numbers "50, 49, ... 1" come from?

Comment: @adamnfish, pcntAnimationComplt = Math.abs(50 - Math.round((parseFloat(currImgWidth / pageWidth) * 100) / 2)); works perfectly if you put it in an answer you can have some points

Comment: @Mark, it's contained within a recursive function that moves elements around an HTML page.

Comment: Your question is unclear on whether your number varies from 0 to 50 or from 1 to 50. I'm assuming that it's the former because it seems to be a progress bar and 0% is a valid amount for a progress bar.

Comment: Sorry I did phrase it badly I can see now.  It's a percentage value, ranging from 0% to 50% and I just need to mirror the numbers, so 50=0, 25=25, 40=10 etc.

Comment: The pic of Bush was amusing but it didn't really help with explaining the question so I removed it. I apologize for being a spoil sport. :)

Comment: No problem I've rephrased the question now incase anyone finds it at a later date

Comment: +1 for your edit. It's much easier to see what the question is now.

Comment: -1 for the answer is a very simple math equation which a 10 year old can answer

Comment: @Numenor: that's what i was thinking...come on Tom, get with the picture. :P

Comment: The original question said I was having a brain fart and just couldn't work it out for some reason, sorry I guess!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `j = max_i - i + min_i` where the two constants min_i and max_i are the lower and upper limit of the range.

If i is always between 0 and 50 then you can just write `j = 50 - i`.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you want to define a function like this:

```
(x)      f(x)
 0        50
 1        49
 2        48
 :         :
48         2
49         1
50         0
```

Then the function is simply:

```
f(x) = 50 - x
```

More generally, if `x` is between `low` and `high` inclusive, then:

```
f(x) = (high + low) - x
```

---

#### Other functions of interest

Here are some other common functions:

```
(x)    f(x)___
 0       0    |
 1       0    3
 2       0 ___|
 3       1    |
 4       1    3     f(x) = x / 3
 5       1 ___|           where / is integer division
 6       2    |
 7       2    3
 :       : ___|

(x)    f(x)___
 0       0    |
 1       1    3
 2       2 ___|
 3       0    |
 4       1    3     f(x) = x % 3
 5       2 ___|           where % is integer remainder
 6       0    |
 7       1    3
 :       : ___|
```

Both of the above are sometimes combined when indexing a 2-dimensional table:

```
  ______4 columns______
 /                     \
 _______________________     (x)   row(x)   col(x)
|     |     |     |     |     0      0        0
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |     1      0        1
|_____|_____|_____|_____|     2      0        2      row(x) = x / 4
|     |     |     |     |     3      0        3      col(x) = x % 4
|  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |     4      1        0
|_____|_____|_____|_____|     5      1        1      x = row(x) * 4 + col(x)
|     |     |     |           6      1        2
|  8  |  9  | ... |           7      1        3
|_____|_____|_____|           :      :        :
```

Comment: Upvoting you not because of your ability to answer a question directly, but because of a nice implicit demonstration of a way to solve problems in general.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading that correctly, the only way for the `pcntAnimationComplt` to go down is if your `currImgWidth` is decreasing. If that is so, then just do this:

```
pcntAnimationComplt = 50 - Math.round((parseFloat(currImgWidth / pageWidth) * 100) / 2);
```

This should go from 0 to 50, as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var min=1;
var max=50;
for(var i=min;i<=max;i++){document.writeln(i + "<br>");}
for(var i=max;i>=min;i--){document.writeln(i + "<br>");}
```